# Error TS1128 Build:Declaration or statement expected in Angular 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, angular, asp.net-core

I have update my dependency of asp.net core 1.0 to asp.net core 1.1.Using the nuget manager. I , have updated all the list in the upload mention in the nuget update. Now, I am getting a **Error   TS1128  Build:Declaration or statement expected**. I, have some google and found that I, am using the old type script.I have install the latest version of type script from this link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/09/22/announcing-typescript-2-0/

[image: tsc version]

Visual studio keeps showing me the error. How, do I resolve this issue in angular 2.

Getting error in this line of code after update before it was ok.

```
LoadMarketItem(page : number) {
        this._pagination = [];
        this.DashBoardservice.GetMarketListCall(page).subscribe(
            data => {
                this.listMarket = data; 
                for(var i = 1; i <= this.listMarket.totalPage; i++){
                    this._pagination.push(new PaginationViewModel(i));
            },    --> getting errror here
            err => { console.log(err); });
    }
```

Comment: What are the results of the `tsc --version` and `where tsc` commands?

Comment: Please check the TSC version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have lost one '}' after for loop.